# Is there a valid way to use string formatting and still sanitize data in Python code for sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3

def delete_data(db_name, table, col, search_condition):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as conn:
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            code_piece = (f"FROM {table} WHERE {col}={search_condition}",)
            self.cur.execute("DELETE ?", code_piece)
```

Taking the above code, is the data the from the function arguments sanitized or is there still a possibility of an sql injection attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Understanding QStyle Parameters

Here's a fix for a bunch of syntactical errors in your code example that prevent it from running:

```
def delete_data(db_name, table, col, search_condition):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        code_piece = (f"FROM {table} WHERE {col}={search_condition}",)
        cur.execute("DELETE ?", code_piece)
```

If you would actually run this function, it would throw an exception on the last line that should read sth like the following:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Why? As far as I know, you cannot use qstyle parameters to cover anything but what could slot in as a value in a valid SQL statement; you cannot use it to replace large parts of a statement; you also can't replace table names. The piece of code that is closest to your intent that could run without raising an exception, is the following code:

```
def delete_data(db_name, col, search_condition):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ?=?;", (col, search_condition,))
```

However, imagine if your table had an actual column called PRICE, with integer values, and several entries had values 5 for that column. The following statement would not delete any of them, because the value of `col` is not interpreted as the name of a column, but slotted in as a string, so you end up comparing the string 'PRICE' with the integer 5 in the WHERE-clause, which would never be true:

```
delete_data("sqlite3.db", 'PRICE', 5)  # DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE 'PRICE'=5;
```

So really, the only thing that your function can end up being, is the following... which is far away from the generic stuff that you were trying to do; however, it uses the qstyle parameters properly, and should be secure from SQL injection:

```
def delete_data(db_name, col, search_condition):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE PRICE=?;", (search_condition,))

delete_data("sqlite3.db", 5);  # DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE PRICE=5;
```

But honestly, this is great, because you really don't want functions that can end up resulting in a bunch of unpredictable queries to your database. My general advise is to just wrap each query in a simple function, and keep it all as simple as possible.

### Your Original Question and SQL Injection

But let's imagine that your original code would actually run as you intended it to. There is nothing that prevents an attacker from abusing any of the parameters to alter the intended purpose of the statement: if user input affects the `table` parameter, it can be used to delete the content of any table; and the `col` and `search_condition` parameters could be altered to delete all entries of a table.

However, it all depends on whether or not an attacker has the ability to alter the values of the parameter through user input. It is unlikely that user input is used directly to select the table or the column to be compared against. However, it would be likely that you would use user input to use as the value of the `search_condition` parameter. If so, then the following function call would be possible.

```
delete_data(db_name, "USERS", "NAME", "Marc OR 1=1"):
```

This would result in the following query to the database, resulting in the deletion of all entries of the USERS table.

```
DELETE FROM USERS WHERE NAME=Marc or 1=1;
```

So yeah, your code was still susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: what the problem for me is when there are more tables in the database. It would mean writing a lot of statements/code. It would be nice to be a able to prototype functions that could handle that, but string formatting is unsafe. Thanks a lot though.